# Starting .NET core web applications on placement in server

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, server, .net-core

I have plans to build .NET core web applications and deploy them to a remote server. I have used Tomcat before with Java and I know Tomcat has a feature in which WAR files placed on the server are expanded and started (with the manager to view and manipulate projects etc.). Are there any similar solution available for servers to run .NET Core applications? That is a service I could place a zip or nupkg file under and the application would be started.

Comment: What HTTP server are you going to be using? E.g. Apache, NGINX, other?

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally .NET does not have application servers like Tomcat/J2EE. There were infrastructural hosts like the IIS on Windows or the Windows Activation system for WCF endpoints, however these are bound to Windows not the modern lightweight approach.

If you want to look into how .NET Core apps should be deployed, I would recommend to look into containerization (eg docker) which is the blessed way of Microsoft. I do not think there are a lot of other high level Tomcat management features which are really standardized for .NET Core.

PS: yes, it is still true: .NET lacks this style of ecosystem. However, it recently picks up the flexibility of node and friends.